# Empty space between affix navbar and content below

Tags: css

I have affix navbar that goes between header and content divs. But there is an empty space for about 20px between navbar and the content div below. Navbar is working, it sticks to top when scroll, but has that white gap when not scroling the page.
Another problem are colors of navbar, they wont change (fonts nor background).

```
<div id="header" class="container-fluid text-center" >
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right bottom">
    <p>"Text"</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="659">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h2>About</h2>
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
   border-radius: 0 !important;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 0;/*not working*/
   padding-bottom: 0;/*not working*/
 }

.wrap {
   background-color: #000;
   margin-top: 0;/*not working*/
   padding-top: 0;/*not working*/
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "margin-top: -18px;" to ".wrap".

Comment: Could you accept my comment as the answer? Thank you)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for the .wrap works, but the suggestion by Max D is actually simpler if you apply to the margin. The following works for me.

```
nav {
margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navbar colors issue solved by adding '!important' to color code.